# Lookup User ID by email - Disqus API

Tags: disqus

Is there any way to look up a Disqus User ID with an email via the Disqus API?

I have a website with Disqus SSO integration, and I need some way to get Disqus user IDs given  the user's email on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but what you can do is lookup comments by users with that email address. You can make this call like this:

```
GET https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/list.json
      api_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
      access_token=YOUR_ADMIN_ACCESS_TOKEN
      query=email:someone@example.com
      include=approved
      include=unapproved
      include=flagged
      include=deleted
      include=spam
```

There's only two things to note:

1. This will only return results for sites you moderate
2. Results will include guest comments, so check for `isAnonymous` in the `author` object.

So as long as you only care about users who have made comments, this should work.

Comment: This doesn't help me in this case... there might be SSO users which haven't left a comment yet on the site, which then would yield no results. I would like to propose of adding an API method which would solve our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is exactly possible, because the user's email may be private.

You can get a user ID for a username by using the users/details and passing in `username:<their username>` as the argument for `user`.

I know that won't help the OP since it's been nearly 8 years since they asked, but maybe this will help someone else (like me) who finds this via a search.